# Firebase onDataChange() function takes very different amount of time to run Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase with my android. I run this code to check if user that logs in with google is stored on the database:

```
val userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/${uidGoogleUser}")
Thread(Runnable {
    userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                val intent = Intent(this@LogInActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
             } else{
                 Log.d("onDataChange", "Does not exist")
                 val intent = Intent(this@LogInActivity, AddUsernameActivity::class.java)
                 startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_USERNAME_REQUEST)

                 if (uidGoogleUser != "" && usernameGoogleUser != "") {
                     storeUserInDatabase(uidGoogleUser, usernameGoogleUser)
                     val intent = Intent(this@LogInActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                     startActivity(intent)
                     finish()
                 }
             }
         }
 })
}).start()
```

When i start the emulator and press the "loggin with google" button it takes REALLY long time before anything happens. If i then get logged in and logs out again, then presses the "loggin with google" button, the process of getting logged in is MUCH faster than the first time. How come this is?

I have had much problem solving this overrall and if anyone get an entirely different idea of how i can do this, please share it. ListenForSingleValueEvent is a long running operations, thats why im running it is a Thread(runnnable), i have looked at coroutines but i don't know how to use them in this solution.

Comment: You might wanna remove the thread and register the listener on main thread. It's a stretch just to start a thread to listen to database changes.

Comment: @Jay I just made it so this runs on a separate thread but eveb before that I had the same problem with that the process takes alot more time when i press the button right when i started the emulator than after logging in and back out and then pressing the "logg in with google" button again.